# Django site very slow to load after restart or period of inactivity

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, httpd.conf

I'm running a Django site on Apache, and am experiencing very slow intial page loads after a period of inactivity (about 1 hour).  I can replicate by leaving for an hour, or bouncing the server.  After the initial load, pages load consistently in < 1 sec.

I'm assuming (guessing) the issue is the Python interpreter + Python modules are being loaded into memory again after these periods of inactivity?

I've followed http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/03/load-spikes-and-excessive-memory-usage.html and am running **mod_wsgi** in daemon mode.

**Server config:**

```
Timeout 20
KeepAlive Off
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15
ServerLimit 10

<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareServers       2
    MaxSpareServers       2
    MaxClients            4
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

...

WSGIDaemonProcess django display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/osqa.wsgi process-group=django application-group=%{GLOBAL}
```

Is something obviously wrong with the config above, or is there a way to keep the Python interpreter in memory?

Perhaps this a different issue altogether?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the output from running the 'top' command?
Can you post the output of the error_log.txt file?

If the problem is reproducible after waiting for about an hour, you should do so and see if python is actually running still by running 'ps -C python' depending on your OS. 

Its very hard to diagnose the issue without more symptoms / information.

Comment: Are you using a cache (memcached ..) because maybe it can be that it's just that now your site was down the cache was clear and what you are observing now is the normal  page load w/o caching, and that the speed that you was experimenting before was because caching optimization ?! you can know if my assumption is correct by (after your website go back to normal) clearing your cache (w/o shutting down your website) and see the diff, of course if you're using a cache framework from the first place :)

Comment: Kevin. That will not help as under mod_wsgi the 'python' executable is not run directly to do stuff. Because they have used display-name option, then the mod_wsgi daemon process using linked Python interpreter will actually be called '(wsgi:django)'. They can check for that, but the configuration is such that it should be there.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I'm facing a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas:

- Make sure you have enough memory and that there is some free and a healthy disk cache available.  You should have at least 1gb to 4+gb total depending on what you are doing.  Top was mentioned, and I recommend htop: http://htop.sourceforge.net/
- Increase disk caching, if for example, you are using an IO poor VM such as EC2/EBS.
- Tune your db to appropriate values with regards to memory.
- If caching check timeouts as mentioned above.  If no one visiting in the hour caches will expire.
- Configure Linux (?) to swap less aggressively:

  - echo 20 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
  - Permanently: add vm.swappiness in /etc/sysctl.conf